# Do the log files which are allocated on agent, controller and datanode can be compressed and archived?

Tags: dolphindb

If a file is written all the time, it will be time-consuming to download and open while troubleshooting. I hope there is a function to compress and archive these files according to the date and size.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the value of maxLogSize in the configuration file to control the archive size of the node's running log.

Description of maxLogSize:

When the log file reaches the specified size (in MB), the system will archive the log file. The default value is 1024, and the minimum value is 100.
Add a prefix to the original log file name as the archived file name. The format of the prefix is . For example, 20181109000 has three digits, starting from 000.

In single mode, configure maxLogSize in dolphindb.cfg to control the size of the dolphindb.log archive file.

In cluster mode, you need to configure maxLogSize in controller.cfg to control the size of the controller.log archive file; at the same time, you need to configure maxLogSize in cluster.cfg to control the size of the datanode.log archive file.